# How to set Intellij Scala console maxmemory

Tags: intellij-idea, jvm

I tried changing the Xmx variable on vmoptions, but it doesn't change anything

The number is stuck as 4.5GB on my 20GB ram machine
and 1834483712 Bytes on my 8GB laptop
Is it set somewhere else? where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is edit the run configuration on the scala console and add the 
 -Xmx8000m to the vm options there instead of the vmoptions file